# How to upload Photos to MySQL and browse

Tags: python, mysql

i'm goging to build fleet management system , and one of modules is " Registration"  so i'm trying to figure out how to upload photos to mysql and browse it again through PyQt5.

```
    def Handel_Buttons(self):

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.browse)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.upload)
        


    def browse (self):
        photo1 = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', 'c:\\',"Image files (*.jpg *.gif *.png *.ico *.jpeg)") 
        self.url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(photo1[0])
        


    def upload(self):
        mydb = con.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password='''''', database="photos") 
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        photo1 = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', 'c:\\',"Image files (*.jpg *.gif *.png *.ico *.jpeg)") 
        self.url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(photo1[0])
        
        with open(self.url, 'rb') as file:
                binaryData = file.read()
                return binaryData

        try:          
            query = ''' INSERT INTO photo (photo1) VALUES (%s)'''

            mycursor.execute(query,(binaryData), )
            mydb.commit()
            self.lineEdit.setText("Image Uploaded sucessfully")

        except con.Error as e:
            self.lineEdit.setText("Image Uploaded failed" + e)
```

Appreciate your support to transform that idea to physical code.
Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decode the photo to string base 64 and then you can store it as  encoded_string.

after you read it from the db you use the decoded_string to show it
there is example also how to show the photo

```
import base64

image = 'img.jpeg'
 with open(image, "rb") as image_file:
    image_bytes = image_file.read()
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_bytes).decode("utf-8")
    print(type(encoded_string), encoded_string)

    decoded_string = encoded_string.encode("utf-8")
    decoded_string = base64.b64decode(decoded_string)
    print(type(decoded_string), decoded_string)
```

Comment: i got that error TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple

Comment: encoded_string should be str.
so make sure you do the commit with the right varibels.